# WM_MOUSELEAVE is received fine, WM_MOUSEHOVER is not -- Mouse Tracking Issues within a window

Tags: c++, winapi

I am experiencing issues tracking my mouse within a window. I have a couple of questions and have not been able to find any related information.

I have a standard message handler written in my window procedure, and have written the necessary cases for mouse tracking as such:

```
case(WM_LBUTTONDOWN) :
{
    /* Other information involving writing a simple string consisting of mouse coordinates
        and the matching window message to a static member for DrawText to use.
    */
    break;
}
case(WM_MOUSEMOVE) :
{
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT me{};
    me.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
    me.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
    me.hwndTrack = m_hwnd;
    me.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
    TrackMouseEvent(&me);
    /* Other information involving writing a simple string consisting of mouse coordinates
        and the matching window message to a static member for DrawText to use.
    */
    break;
}
case(WM_LBUTTONUP) :
{
    /* Other information involving writing a simple string consisting of mouse coordinates
        and the matching window message to a static member for DrawText to use.
    */
    break;
}
case(WM_MOUSEHOVER) :
{
    /* Other information involving writing a simple string consisting of mouse coordinates
        and the matching window message to a static member for DrawText to use.
    */
    break;
}
case(WM_MOUSELEAVE) :
{
    /* Other information involving writing a simple string consisting of mouse coordinates
        and the matching window message to a static member for DrawText to use.
    */
    break;
}
```

The `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message seems to be handled easily, resulting in a nice `"MOUSELEAVE"` message being printed to my on-screen console.

However, the `WM_MOUSEHOVER` message is not handled, for whatever reason. I have tried initializing another `TRACKMOUSEEVENT` and defining its related members to the same values as in the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, but this results in no success.

What could be the cause of this strangeness? I have looked at other questions in this area, but have found no solution.

Also, when including a `TRACKMOUSEEVENT` locally in the window class that defines the window procedure, `TrackMouseEvent()` does not work to display a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` or `WM_MOUSEHOVER` message, what could be the cause of this?

Comment: "*when including a `TRACKMOUSEEVENT` locally in the window class*" - what do you mean?

Comment: I have the functions necessary for the management of a window (including the window procedure) in a window class, and have tried declaring a `TRACKMOUSEEVENT` member in the class to be used by `TrackMouseEvent()`, but this only results in *no* message being displayed -- neither `WM_MOUSELEAVE` nor `WM_MOUSEHOVER` is captured this way -- I thought it odd.

Comment: a) are you sure the TrackMouseEvent got called. b) did you try changing the hover timeout fom HOVER_DEFAULT to something explicit

Comment: I am sure `TrackMouseEvent` was called because `WM_MOUSELEAVE` is handled -- I will double check this. I have also tried setting the timeout to 2000 (milliseconds), but this did not result in success.

Comment: "*but this only results in no message being displayed*" - then you need to provide a [mcve] showing exactly what you are doing. Aside from that, the only oddity I see is that you are using your class's `m_hwnd` member instead of using the `HWND` provided to the window procedure. Are you sure `m_hwnd` is pointing where you expect it at the time `TrackMouseEvent()` is called? Have you checked with `SystemParametersInfo()` to make sure that hovering is even enabled? See `SPI_GETMOUSEHOVER(WIDTH|HEIGHT)` and `SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME`. Did you check if `TrackMouseEvent()` is returning `FALSE`?

Comment: Yes, `TrackMouseEvent` can be confirmed to be called. It is working.

Comment: This is from the [`WM_MOUSELEAVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseleave) documentation: *"All tracking requested by `TrackMouseEvent` is canceled when this message is generated. The application must call `TrackMouseEvent` when the mouse reenters its window if it requires further tracking of mouse hover behavior."*

Comment: Calling `SystemParametersInfo()` gives me a hover width of 4px and a hover height of 4px. The default `SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME` gives me a value of 400 (ms). I also experimented with supplying the `HWND` argument given to the window procedure to the `TRACKMOUSEEVENT` object, but I still do not seem to be receiving `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages -- though `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages are received simply.

Comment: I see now that the receiving of a `WM_MOUSEHOVER` message is dependent on `BeginPaint()` being called in the `WM_PAINT` case of my window procedure. However, this call causes my functions that are dependent on the `BeginDraw()` method of my `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` to become unresponsive, and if I call `InvalidateRect()`, `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages are no longer received. Is this because of the interoperability between GDI and Direct2D, or am I missing something essential here? WM_MOUSELEAVE messages are received fine if I include a call to `InvalidateRect()` after `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()`.

Comment: I have solved the issue by leaving a simple call to the `BeginPaint()` and `EndPaint()` functions in the `WM_PAINT` case and moving all drawing functions to directly under the message translator and dispatcher in `WinMain`. I suppose this is creative thinking, though I believe this sort of "architecture" may be the first sign of my being headed in the right direction. Thank you for the help, friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Mouse Tracking Events: Hover and Leave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/other-mouse-operations#mouse-tracking-events-hover-and-leave)

> After you get one of the messages that you requested, the
> `TrackMouseEvent function` resets. You must call it again to get another
> tracking message. However, you should wait until the next mouse-move
> message before calling `TrackMouseEven`t again. Otherwise, your window
> might be flooded with tracking messages. For example, if the mouse is
> hovering, the system would continue to generate a stream of
> `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages while the mouse is stationary. You don't
> actually want another `WM_MOUSEHOVER message` until the mouse moves to
> another spot and hovers again.

And there is an official sample on the doc, which you can refer to.

Comment: I seem to have followed these instructions step-by-step in my own code and still have no success in receiving `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages. I am unsure as to why this could be the case even with the `dwFlags` member of `TRACKMOUSEEVENT` set to `TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE`, resulting in the successful receiving of `WM_MOUSELEAVE` events but not the former. I will have to do some experimentation -- I am going to try writing a simple window program.

Comment: By writing a simple program with a message handler I have discovered that the `WM_MOUSELEAVE` and `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages are being delivered correctly. Now I must translate this to my current program -- very strange.